# how to get related images from one object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have a one to many relation. One Attraction can have many images for the attraction. The attractionImages-Table have the foreignkey id from the table attraction.

I tried to get the images with the following controller function:

```
public function attractionIndexAction( $id )
{
    $attractionRepo = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository( "RowocoAllgemeinBundle:Attraction")
        ->find( $id );

    $attractionImagesRepo = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository( "RowocoAllgemeinBundle:AttractionImages" )
        ->find( $attractionRepo );

    return $this->render("RowocoAllgemeinBundle:Attraction:attraction.html.twig",
            array(
                "attraction"        => $attractionRepo,
                "attractionImages"  => $attractionImagesRepo
            )
    );
}
```

In the html.twig i try to view the result like this:

```
{% for image in attraction.attractionImages %}
<li data-thumb="/attractionimages/{{ image.folder }}/thumb/{{ image.filename }}">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/attractionimages/{{ image.folder }}/{{ image.filename }}" />
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The Repo had the result, but i cant view it in the twig-file.

This is the doctrine xml:

```
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="Rowoco\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\AttractionImages" table="attraction_images">
    <indexes>
      <index name="ait_ai_fk1_idx" columns="id_attraction_imagestype"/>
      <index name="a_ai_fk2_idx" columns="id_attraction"/>
    </indexes>
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="folder" type="string" column="folder" length="155" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="filename" type="string" column="filename" length="255" nullable="false"/>
    <field name="locked" type="integer" column="locked" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="proofed" type="integer" column="proofed" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="addate" type="datetime" column="addate" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="slider" type="integer" column="slider" nullable="true"/>
    <many-to-one field="idAttraction" target-entity="Attraction">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="id_attraction" referenced-column-name="id"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one field="idAttractionImagestype" target-entity="AttractionImagestype">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="id_attraction_imagestype" referenced-column-name="id"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your images are not in `attraction`, because you are passing it as a separate object, using the array key `attractionImages`. Try:

```
{% for image in attractionImages %}
<li data-thumb="/attractionimages/{{ image.folder }}/thumb/{{ image.filename }}">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/attractionimages/{{ image.folder }}/{{ image.filename }}" />
</li>
{% endfor %}
```